# What is the image of a void function?

Tags: function, mapping, set, map-projections

If functions are borrowed from the mathematical concept of mapping a value from some set **S** onto **T**, then the function:

```
int increment(int input)
{
    return input + 1;
}
```

would be the mapping from the integers onto the integers. And so the logic goes for most functions, but what about if the return value of a function is void. Does that still fit the mathematical paradigm, or is that a departure, or what is that?